# Object search works first time only

Tags: javascript, object

I created an object called "Jarz".  Then added an object within it called 'cat'.  Then I made a function to search within the Jarz object for an object called 'cat', which works.  However for every object after 'cat' that I add to 'Jarz' the function will not find it in the search.  Only the first run ever works.  Here is the code:

```
var Jarz = {};

Jarz['cat'] = {};
```

Here is the function:

```
function doesObjExist(ObjName){
var tmpArr = Object.keys(Jarz);
for(var i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++){
    if(tmpArr[i] === ObjName){
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

When I run it on the first object 'cat' it returns true.  But any obj I make after that returns false. ie:

```
Jarz['hat'] = {};
doesObjExist('hat')  // returns false
```

I cant seem to find what is missing here.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Move `return false` to after the `for` loop.

Comment: Yup that's it. It's checking the first one, and since it doesn't match (cos it's hat now, not cat) it's returning false

Comment: Also note that `Jarz.hasOwnProperty('hat');` seems to do just what you want aswell

Comment: Walk though your code with the debugger.

Comment: Leaving all other problems with your code aside, avoid the antipattern of `if (b) return true; else return false`. Just `return b;`. In this case, `return tmpArr[i] === ObjName;` (although that won't do what you want in this case).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because when you call it with hat, it is checking first for cat as it is false your returning from the loop so it won't execute further to check for hat.

Change this to:

```js
var Jarz = {};

Jarz['cat'] = {};
console.log(doesObjExist('cat'));
Jarz['hat'] = {};
console.log(doesObjExist('hat'));

function doesObjExist(ObjName) {
  var tmpArr = Object.keys(Jarz);
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++) {
    if (tmpArr[i] === ObjName) {
      return true;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (count >= tmpArr.length)
    return false;
}
```